# How to Escape BackTicks Within a Blockquote

Tags: discussion, markdown, code-formatting, blockquote

This is close to being a duplicate question, but I'm adding it to make it easier to find the answer in searches.

Question:

How do you include backtick characters within a blockquote? For instance, to post an error message which refers to a .NET generic class like List`1:

> This is an error message which refers to a .NET generic class like List`1

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use a backslash before the backtick, like

```
> This is an error message which refers to a .NET generic class like List\`1
```

This escapes the backtick character, even within a blockquote.

Comment: this applies to escaping almost anything in Markdown FYI

Comment: I think this is broken when escaping two backtick chars in a row in an answer (though it seems to work fine in comments). e.g. backtick\backtick\backtickbacktick doesn't escape properly in an answer (at least on SO).